# What to do when a type contains itself?

Tags: haskell

I have code that works for a monad that's constrained to have some state.
I'm having a problem because the state has a type variable that requires the monad.

It looks like:

```
myget :: MonadState (MyState m A) m => m A
```

Now when I try to make it more specific, there's a problem. E.g. just with `StateT` (on some inner-monad `im`):

```
myget' :: StateT <loops here> im A
myget' :: StateT (MyState <loop> A) im A
myget' :: StateT (MyState (MyState <loop> A) A) im A
myget' :: StateT (MyState (MyState (MyState <loop> A) A) A) im A
...
myget' = myget
```

So obviously I can't write this type signature; I can't even leave it for type-inference.

How can I solve this?
I did kind of solve it by making `myget` (the first, general definition) work on a monad transformer instead, and it did work, but then the code doesn't play nicely with anything else (because usually people work with monads transformers as just monads), so it's not a really good solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html

Comment: What does `MyState` look like, by the way?

Comment: Can you define your own monad, `MSM`, with an instance that's something along the lines of `MonadState (MyState MSM A) MSM`?

Comment: @dfeuer `MyState m a` looks like a record of `{msValue :: a, msValidate :: m Bool}` (in the actual code it's authentication data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newtype` to the rescue! A `newtype` or `data` declaration can break a loop.

```
newtype MS s m a = MS
  {getMS :: StateT (MyState (MS s m) s) m a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

deriving instance Monad m =>
  MonadState (MyState (MS s m) s) (MS s m)

instance MonadTrans (MS s) where
  lift = MS . lift
```

Comment: That's great! I couldn't get the form correctly; thank you so much! P.S. `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` was enough to derive the instance.

Comment: @MasterMastic, I swapped the argument order just now to get a `MonadTrans` instance. I'm not at my computer, so I don't know if GND can derive that too.

Comment: Yeah, `MonadTrans` usually doesn't work out for me with generalized newtype deriving, but that's the only one. And it's good that you did flip it; now there's the usual order.

Comment: I'm actually still facing an issue: how can you "run" this your inner-monad? e.g. `s -> MS s m a -> m (a,s)`.

Comment: @MasterMastic, Given `runMyState s (MS m) = runStateT m s`, GHC infers `runMyState :: MyState (MS t m) t -> MS t m a -> m (a, MyState (MS t m) t)`, which seems reasonable. I kind of wonder if you could simplify things by refraining from bundling the authentication action with the state object, but I don't know nearly enough about your application to say.

Comment: Fair enough; I found it much more usable after making sure to only use it on the first inner `m` occurrence (it was on both initially because of an already existing newtype). I was literally stuck inside the monad :P. Now it's completely fine after I noticed that. Thanks again!